# Form WHERE clause

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an APEX form I'm developing for "user settings". I have a table with a sequence as a primary key and the users ID in another column...in addition to a few columns where each users saved settings are stored (things like "N" for do not receive notices).

I haven't used Oracle APEX in a while so excuse this likely newbie question...The insert works fine, but I'm having trouble with making the form only show the current users values. In my Form Region the source is set to my Table, and I have a WHERE clause like this:

USER_ID = 813309

But that's not working (813309 is my id and I'm just hard-coding it for now). The form always comes up with a "New" record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a form to load a specific record you can set the primary key page item to the value you need. You can do so in the url using the link builder from another page or you can set a computation on the item. That is what I would try in your case: add a computation to your item P_USER_ID of type "Static Value" with value 813309. Make sure the computation happens before the "Fetch Row" - the value obviously needs to be set before the process runs.

Comment: Thanks for this...I had this same thing in one of my buttons on another page, but was concerned for this being secure...i.e., what's to stop a user from simply changing the  query string to some other ID? Then I tried it myself and it looks like APEX includes a checksum query string parameter that protects against this...so this is what I'll use!

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, I prefer creating a *Report + Form* combination (using the Wizard, of course): it creates an interactive report (so that you can review data in a table), and a form which is used to add new records or update/delete existing ones.

Doing so, when you pick a user in interactive report and click the icon at the beginning of a row, Apex redirects you to the form page, passing primary key column value to the form which then fetches appropriate data from the table.

Not that it won't work the way you're trying to do it, it's just simpler if you let Apex do everything for you.

So: did you create an automatic row fetch pre-rendering process? If not, do so because - without it - Apex doesn't know what to fetch. Also, if you hardcoded `user_id`, it won't do much good. Consider storing username into the table so that you could reference it via `:APP_USER` Apex variable.

Comment: Thanks...I wanted the nav menu as well as some buttons to take the user to the page, not have to use a Report to get there, and only show them THEIR values. And yes, I'm using APP_USER I was just hard-coding (with my own ID) to test and get it working. And Yes, I have an auto-row fetch because I used the wizard to create the page (form) originally. :)